# Webpack Encore & jQuery plugin : $(...).isotope is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, yarnpkg, jquery-isotope, webpack-encore

I'm working on a Symfony5 project, with Yarn & jQuery. I have an error when I try to use the jQuery plugin "[isotope-layout](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/)" with Webpack Encore.

I try to fix it for many hours but I might not be doing it the right way.

Here is my code :

**webpack.config.js**

```
// Same error with or without "autoProvidejQuery"
Encore.autoProvidejQuery();
```

**app.js**

```
import 'jquery';
import 'popper.js';
import 'bootstrap';
import 'isotope-layout';

// start the Stimulus application
import './bootstrap';
```

**custom.js**

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';
import 'isotope-layout';

(function ($) {

    // Here is the error :
    $(...).isotope({...});

})(jQuery);
```

**Error :**

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).isotope is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use jQuery when using Isotope. You can use this example from [their Webpack documentation](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/extras.html#webpack):

```
var Isotope = require('isotope-layout');

var iso = new Isotope( '.grid', {
  // options...
});
```

There is also an example if you want to use jQuery. To install it:

```
npm install jquery
npm install jquery-bridget
```

And than:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var jQueryBridget = require('jquery-bridget');
var Isotope = require('isotope-layout');
// make Isotope a jQuery plugin
jQueryBridget( 'isotope', Isotope, $ );
// now you can use $().isotope()
$('.grid').isotope({
  // options...
});
```

If you're using modern Javascript (and you're using Webpack, great!), [you might not need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) in many cases.