# Import Bootstrap & plugin Carousel with Webpack Encore

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5, webpack-encore, bootstrap-carousel

I'm working on a Symfony project with Webpack Encore and I have a problem with loading Bootstrap and the plugin Carousel.

It could come from the import of Bootstrap because it's seems to work (but not fully) when I import the file:

```
import './styles/bootstrap.min.css';
```

But the slider is not working at all when I import properly the package from 'node_modules':

```
import 'bootstrap';
```

And no error in the console.
Here is my code :

**app.css**

```
@import '~bootstrap';
@import url('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?language=en');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700');
```

**app.js**

```
//import './styles/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap';
```

**slider.js**

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';

// make Carousel a jQuery plugin
import Carousel from 'bootstrap/js/dist/carousel';
import jQueryBridget from 'jquery-bridget';
jQueryBridget('carousel', Carousel, jQuery);

;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 10000
        });
    });
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: try to understand what you're doing. While Webpack is used to compile [JavaScript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules), jQuery is a library that has been developed when JS wasn't that modern. Nowadays, [you might not need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) anymore. So you're combining modern JS with legacy JS. While it can work, don't try it if you don't need it.

Bootstrap 5 doesn't need jQuery. So why use it? Take a look at the example from [Bootstrap's own documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/#methods):

```
var myCarousel = document.querySelector('#myCarousel')
var carousel = new bootstrap.Carousel(myCarousel, {
  interval: 2000,
  wrap: false
})
```

So this should be enough:

```
var myCarousel = document.querySelector('.carousel')
var carousel = new bootstrap.Carousel(myCarousel, {
  interval: 1000
})
```

Since you've had [similar problems before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68510479/webpack-encore-jquery-plugin-isotope-is-not-a-function), I really suggest to read the documentation of the libraries you want to use. Usually they provide good examples you can use.

TL;DR: stop using jQuery and start reading documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will follow it for sure. But in this case, I must use the template [Prague](https://preview.themeforest.net/item/prague-architecture-and-interior-design-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/19618927?_ga=2.261986317.1850477900.1628252112-1279012034.1621955597) for a client, and jQuery is already used by few plugins. Do you think I must rewrite all the code, or there is a simpler solution for a first step ?

Comment: If you don't need jQuery, don't use it. And if there's jQuery in a project, that doesn't mean you have to use it everyone in the project. You don't need to rewrite all the code, but for this specific case (the Bootstrap Carousel) you don't need jQuery.

Comment: Got it ! Thanks a lot to take time to answer, it's very helpful